# WPF: How to achieve visual print of UIElement into multiple pages?

Tags: wpf, printing, scrollviewer, uielement, multipage

I have several controls in a `ScrollViewer` which when printed should span multiple pages both horizontally and vertically.  My current solution uses a series of scrolls (both in horizontal & vertical direction) to achieve the printing.

For this implementation to work the content of the ScrollView needs to be disassociated and added to a new `ScrollViewer` (the new instance of `ScrollViewer` is adjusted to `PrintWidth` and Height to achieve the print objective), as a result the original view will be emptied.  To overcome this problem, I have  tried Cloning the entire `ScrollViewer`, but this seems to fail with bindings - `DataGrid` is displayed empty in the cloned visual.

**Is there any other approach where the visual elements can be printed, or, are there any other approach (perhaps using `VisualBrush`) to achieve the objective of multi page print?**